# How to use values from one section of view dynamically in a different section before submit?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, omnifaces

We have a need where sections could be added and removed dynamically in one screen which need to be used in a different section in the same screen dynamically before submit.

Adding/removing, binding is the easier part which I have done, but the part I am struggling with is not seeing the values from the earlier section that get entered in the later section which the values are referenced/used again.

There is no value in the backing bean for the first section which when used later in the other section show blank which makes sense as submit has not occurred, but how to use the values entered in first sections that should be available in the model to be used in the later section?

Example:
Primary family member - adds other family members in the first section.
The primary and secondary family members should show in different subscriptions/memberships that they could be a part of and all this is on the same form.

I have a hard time explaining the issue, hopefully you have understood and are able to suggest a solution? I hope I dont have to define and use valuechangelisteners to each field.

We are using JSF2, Richfaces 4 and omnifaces.

Comment: Why not use ajax powers to execute/render components you want? The logic becomes the following: a new person is added, in action method you decide in which subscription list to put that person and then you update the table containing people's subscriptions. What is the problem with this approach? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: The component does get rendered, but the values are not saved on the backing bean yet as the submit of the form has not occurred, so the values show as blank. Even before submit, we need to show the subscriptions/memberships as well as the family members that are part of it whose information is still getting entered in the same form.

Comment: Code? Where is the code. This is all too abstract. A lot of this sounds like what you need is a purely client-side solution anyway

Comment: I realized that what I was looking for was a client side changes with values updated to the bound bean attributes using f:ajax. One thing I am not liking is if a section has say 6 fields and I am using f:ajax with listener on two of the fields, when I render the section, the values of the input components that were not one of the ones with f:ajax get cleared as they are not set on the backing bean. I know adding a dummy listener and calling that from each input component would get that set, but I am interested to find out if there is a way to not have f:ajax on each input field?